# mock a function call using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, hottowel

Getting started with [HotTowelAngular](http://www.johnpapa.net/hot-towel-angular/) template and I'm setting up unit testing. Ran into a snag.

I'm trying to test a function in my controller that happens to call another function named "log". This "log" is a function stored in a private variable which gets its value from a dependency called "common".

I'm aware that I probably need to stub this function in some way, but I'm unsure of where to start for this particular example, as I'm pretty new to angularjs, jasmine, et all. Any ideas are appreciated

**unit test**:

```
describe("quote", function () {
    var scope,
        controller,
        common;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _common_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        common = _common_;
        controller = $controller;
    }));

 describe("removeAttachment", function() {

        it("should remove the attachment when requested", function() {
            var vm = controller("quote", { $scope: scope });

            vm.attachmentList.push({ FileName: "file1", FileAsString: "..." });
            vm.attachmentList.push({ FileName: "file2", FileAsString: "..." });
            vm.attachmentList.push({ FileName: "file3", FileAsString: "..." });
            expect(vm.attachmentList.length).toEqual(3);

            // here's the call where it fails
            vm.removeAttachment(vm.attachmentList[1]);

            expect(vm.attachmentListCount).toEqual(2);
            expect(vm.attachmentList.length).toEqual(2);
            expect(vm.attachmentList[1].FileName).toBe("file3");
        });
    });
 });
```

**controller:**

```
 var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
 var log = getLogFn(controllerId);

 function removeAttachment(attachment) {

        // need to stub this out
        log('removing attachment: ' + attachment.FileName);

        vm.attachmentList.splice(vm.attachmentList.indexOf(attachment), 1);
        vm.attachmentListCount = vm.attachmentList.length;
    }
```

The **error** from Jasmine:

*TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'log('removing attachment: ' + attachment.FileName)')*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your test you should have controller = $contoller("YourController", {it's dependencies});

You probably don't want to pass in your *common* service, but create a stub that returns a function.

```
var  wrapper = {logger: function () {}};
var stub = { logger: { getLogFun: function() {return wrapper.logger} }};
```

You can pass that in place of your common service.

You can now spy on it with:

```
spyOn(wrapper, 'logger');
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `var log = getLogFn(controllerId)` being called before removeAttachment? Is getLogFn() injected into the controller? If these are both true, you could stub out getLogFn() to return a dummy log object that you could use for testing. I am not aware of hottowel, I use [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/). In [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), I would call

`var getLogFnStub = sinon.stub().returns(function (msg) { return 1;/*My expected result*/ });`

and pass that into your controller, like

`var vm = controller("quote", { $scope: scope, getLogFn: getLogFnStub});`

If you wanted, you could then do asserts against the stub you made in [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), like so

```
sinon.assert.called(getLogFnStub);
```